# Test multi storage in laravel

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-10, laravel-storage

I have a issue while trying to mock multi `Storage` in laravel test enviromnment.

Here is my my code:

```php
public function sftp ( Sibling $sibling ) {
        $file_paths = Storage::build($sibling->config)
                             ->files($this->track->track_token);
        Storage::disk('public')
               ->makeDirectory($this->track->track_token);
        foreach ( $file_paths as $file_path ) {
            $file_content = Storage::build($sibling->config)
                                   ->get($file_path);
            TrackMp3::query()
                    ->where('track_id' , $this->track->id)
                    ->where('file_name' , basename($file_path))
                    ->update([
                                 'downloaded_at' => now() ,
                             ]);
            Storage::disk('public')
                   ->put($file_path , $file_content);
        }
    }
```

Here is my test case:

```
public function test_sftp_works_when_track_exists_in_sibling () {
        $track_token = md5('sample');
        $track_320 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                 ->create('track_320.mp3')
                                 ->getContent();
        $track_160 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                 ->create('track_160.mp3')
                                 ->getContent();
        $track_96 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                ->create('track_96.mp3')
                                ->getContent();
        $track_demo = UploadedFile::fake()
                                  ->create('track_demo.mp3')
                                  ->getContent();
        $sibling = SiblingFactory::new()
                                 ->create();
        $public_disk = Storage::fake('public');
        $sibling_disk = Storage::fake('sibling');
        Storage::shouldReceive('build')
               ->with($sibling->config)
               ->andReturn($sibling_disk);
        $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_320.mp3' , $track_320);
        $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_160.mp3' , $track_160);
        $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_96.mp3' , $track_96);
        $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_demo.mp3' , $track_demo);
        $track = TrackFactory::new()
                             ->md5Fetched()
                             ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_320.mp3')) ])
                                                  ->fileName320())
                             ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_160.mp3')) ])
                                                  ->fileName160())
                             ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_96.mp3')) ])
                                                  ->fileName96())
                             ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_demo.mp3')) ])
                                                  ->fileNameDemo())
                             ->create([ 'track_token' => $track_token ]);

        Storage::fake('public'); // ----> Error happend here
        Artisan::call('download');
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_2_Illuminate_Filesystem_FilesystemManager::createLocalDriver(), but no expectations were specified
C:\Development\projects\track-download-manager\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:353
C:\Development\projects\track-download-manager\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage.php:107
C:\Development\projects\track-download-manager\tests\Feature\DownloadCommandTest.php:55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've called Storage::fake() more than once. first for sibling and then for public. When you call it the second time, Laravel is attempting to create a local disk and because you've mocked the Storage facade earlier, the test breaks.

The key is to set up your fakes before you set up any mocks.

```
$public_disk = Storage::fake('public');
$sibling_disk = Storage::fake('sibling');

Storage::shouldReceive('build')
    ->with($sibling->config)
    ->andReturn($sibling_disk);
```

If you're not checking the interaction with `Storage::build` in this test and only need to make sure that files are correctly placed on the sibling and public disks, consider removing the `shouldReceive('build')` mocking.

If you still face issues, you can reset the mocked instance after you're done with it to ensure no side effects for subsequent calls.

```
Storage::swap($this->app['files']);
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting up fakes before setting up any mocks was the problem as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve it.

I forgot to mock public disk.

```php
    public function test_sftp_works_when_track_exists_in_sibling () {
            $track_token = md5(rand());
            $track_320 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                     ->create('track_320.mp3')
                                     ->getContent();
            $track_160 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                     ->create('track_160.mp3')
                                     ->getContent();
            $track_96 = UploadedFile::fake()
                                    ->create('track_96.mp3')
                                    ->getContent();
            $track_demo = UploadedFile::fake()
                                      ->create('track_demo.mp3')
                                      ->getContent();
            $sibling = SiblingFactory::new()
                                     ->create();
            $public_disk = Storage::fake('public');
            $sibling_disk = Storage::fake('sibling');
            Storage::shouldReceive('build')
                   ->with($sibling->config)
                   ->andReturn($sibling_disk);
            Storage::shouldReceive('disk')
                   ->with('public')
                   ->andReturn($public_disk);
            $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_320.mp3' , $track_320);
            $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_160.mp3' , $track_160);
            $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_96.mp3' , $track_96);
            $sibling_disk->put($track_token . '/track_demo.mp3' , $track_demo);
            $track = TrackFactory::new()
                                 ->md5Fetched()
                                 ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_320.mp3')) ])
                                                      ->fileName320())
                                 ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_160.mp3')) ])
                                                      ->fileName160())
                                 ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_96.mp3')) ])
                                                      ->fileName96())
                                 ->has(TrackMp3Factory::new([ 'md5' => md5_file($sibling_disk->path($track_token . '/track_demo.mp3')) ])
                                                      ->fileNameDemo())
                                 ->create([ 'track_token' => $track_token ]);
    
            Artisan::call('download');
        }
```